# IPython inline ! bang shell command

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

Is there a way to use the IPython `!` (bang) in-line? Or is there a good general Pythonic way of running a shell command and capturing its output in a list or string? You can use Python's `os.listdir` method and other shell wrapper methods, but then you have to know the Python methods that wrap common shell commands.

E.g., using `cat` in-line, `!cat /etc/os-release` (I would normally run this in [JupyterLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook_Applications)) raises a syntax error:

```
In [1]: os_release_info = {(split := info.split('='))[0]:split[1] for info in !cat /etc/os-release}
  File "<ipython-input-4-b5d2c7182f4f>", line 1
    os_release_info = {(split := info.split('='))[0]:split[1] for info in !cat /etc/os-release}
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This, along with the [walrus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions), allows one to do interesting file system output processing in comprehensions.

Otherwise, you have to separate out shell commands via the bang operator on individual lines:

```
Python 3.9.1 (default, Feb  3 2021, 07:04:15)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.20.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: os_release_cat = !cat /etc/os-release

In [2]: os_release_info = {(split := info.split('='))[0]:split[1] for info in os_release_cat}
```

Comment: Try `pathlib.Path("/etc/os-release").read_text().splitlines()` instead.

Comment: You are hopefully already aware that running and parsing shell commands like `ls` is slow, fragile, and full of pitfalls, while `os.listdir` is fast, secure, and robust. Have you considered looking for a library that implements common shell commands in terms of Python?

Comment: The ipython shell can capture the `!` at the start of the line, and in the `var=!cmd` syntax, https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/shell.html#string-lists, but anywhere else it's the Python interpreter that will see the `!` and complain.

Comment: Why is running and parsing shell commands like `ls` "slow, fragile, and full of pitfalls"? At least partially because you are using the shell instead of directly interfacing with the OS?

Comment: What is MRI? [Magnetic resonance imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging)?

Comment: *Why is running and parsing shell commands...fragle?* -- For one thing,  the behavior of shells and commands like `ls` and `cut` is not standardized.  Different systems behave differently.  Your code would not work at all in Windows, whereas `os.listdir` works everywhere.  For another, you are creating large unnecessary overhead by creating another separate process, and loading and initializing a shell.  That which can be done in Python should be done in Python.

Answer (score 2):

[`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) makes it trivial to call out to the shell if you desire. There's a bit of extra stuff you need to do to make it feel like a drop-in replacement for `!`. But it's simple to write a wrapper function that helps with that.

```py
import subprocess

class StringResult:
    def __init__(self, result):
        self.result = result

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(str(self).splitlines())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.result.stdout.decode()

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.result.returncode == 0

def run(*args, **kwargs):
    result = subprocess.run(*args, shell=True, capture_output=True, **kwargs)
    return StringResult(result)

glob = '*.py'
# a very silly way to print "py" if any .py files exist
for line in run(f'ls -1 {glob} | cut -d . -f 2 | sort | uniq'):
    print(line)

if run('which python3'):
    print('Python 3 exists on this machine')
```

This is all well and fine for a bit of manual hacking, but if you're writing a program or script, then you'd be better off using the native features of Python.